# Unknown Exception when entering particular keystrokes in Notepad++

Tags: windows-7, notepad++

When I enter the keystrokes <kbd>-</kbd><kbd>></kbd> in a normla file, everting works fine. When I put in `<?php` and use the same keystrokes again, than a `unknown exception` appears. If i delete `<?php` and try it again, everything works well again. What could this be ?

- I searched in the Internet, no results.
- I tried to reinstall all my plugins, no result.
- I updated my np++, no result. (On my work I use the same version. It works there!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason why this happend.

For all who may have the same problem.

I had a followwing plugin installed **ACCPC**

> **Plugin description**
>
> This plugin implements code completion for custom PHP classes in Notepad++. Keep an overview over your classes' attributes & methods in a nice popup!
>
> A popup window appears after typing the "->" or "::" behind a class or an instantiated object variable which displays all attributes and methods of it's class. As soon as the popup appears you can type in the name of the method or attribute you are looking for and the plugin will select it in the list automatically. Hitting [return] or double clicking the entry will insert the name of the property to your script. Additionally, there is a list with all classes and their properties in a dockable window. Double clicking this entries opens their file & jumps right to the declaration. The list offers a quick search function also.
>
> Author: Stanislav Eckert
>
> Source: https://sourceforge.net/p/accpc/code/HEAD/tree/
>
> Homepage: https://sourceforge.net/projects/accpc/
>
> Latest update: 16.04.2014 (v1.3)
>
> - Class constants and static attributes / methods can now be accessed by the "::" operator and are not visible in the popup for `"->"` operator anymore

As you can see the update did some with the keystroke I am using. Now I am not really sure if this update was the reason but since I deinstalled this plugin, it works.

Answer (score 1):

you have to open the Plugins Manager and reinstall ACCPC, after that, you have to choose setting it from menu: Plugins -> ACCPC -> Settings; and choose your root folder contains all your php file or your project.

Comment: This is exactly what I did. But in my case this doesnt solve my problem because am using notepad++ to edit files directly on my ftp. So they are dropped into my temp folder. I also have a xampp project root where my projects a placed. In the xampp folder everthing works but not in all others. I also use a ftp plugin so get all files into my project pathes but there is a lot of configuration to do for each project and so its better for me to simply deinstall this plugin. Even if i would prefer to use this. Plugin update for multiply folders would be nice :)